# How to write on the second line of a text file, ignoring the first line?

Tags: python-3.x, seek

I want to write into a text file from the second line.

At the moment to write data onto a text file I use:

```
with open("data1.txt", "w") as file:

    file.write(str(round(strength, 2)) + "\n")

file.close()
```

'Strength' as in a value(Number)

To read from a specific line (The second line in this case) from the text file:

```
with open("data1.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:

    S1 = file.readlines()
    S1 = float(S1[1].strip())
file.close()
```

How can I write onto a file from the second line starting with:

```
with open("data1.txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
```

I know that to write from the beginning of the text file I need to use:

```
file.seek(0)
```

How can I replace/change/write from the second line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to read the file first:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Then change the second line:

```
lines[1] = str(round(strength, 2)) + "\n"
```

Then write everything back:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    for line in lines:
        file.write(line)
```

Comment: No, `with` block will close the file for you.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this is by reading the first line using `file.readline()`, counting the number of characters in the first line using `len(file.readline())` then using `file.seek(len(file.readline()) + 1)` to begin writing from that position, i.e. the next line.

You may need to alter the `+1`, I haven't tested this.

Comment: see abacaba... whatever his name is - his answer